# USB to AUX driver

Tags: usb, drivers, adapter

I have an old "singstar" adapter. It has two aux ports that go to one USB plug. The adapter is made to work with a PS3 so I wonder if it is possible to use it with my computer.

What i want it to do is:

1: Connect a microphone (ingoing aux) to my computer through USB (what it was invented to do, just with a PS3)

or

2: Use it as an outgoing aux (speakers, headphones, etc) through USB

If it is possible to do any of this, where can I find a universal driver for a USB to AUX adapter?

Comment: There’s no such thing as an “USB to AUX adapter”. It’s an audio interface.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this, please refer to  [Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Using-your-Singstar-microphones-on-a-PC-and-recor). But I don't think it's possible on using it as an outgoing aux concurrently with a microphone.